# Trouble installing Mac OSX Lion theme

Tags: themes, tar

So I wanted to play a prank on some friends and tried to install the Mac OSX Lion theme from NoobsLab [Mac OSX Lion Theme](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/01/install-mac-os-x-lion-theme-on-ubuntu.html).  To this point, I've only dabbled a bit with linux, so I'm still a little shaky on configuring and installing just about ***anything***.

Anyhow, I run the first command per the instructions, but when I run the second one:

`sudo tar -xzvf Mac-Lion-Cursors.tar.gz -C /usr/share/icons`

I recieve this error:

```
tar (child): Mac-Lion-Cursors.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

It seems to only occur with commands that begin with `tar`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but it turns out it was an error with the directions.  I had left a comment detailing my problem on the page and they found the problem and fixed it.  Again, thank you for taking time to help me with my problem.

Comment: It would be very useful if you can detail the instructions in your answer and also accept your own answer otherwise the question remains unaccepted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the tar command from the directory (folder) that the .tar.gz file is in?

If it's saved in `~/Downloads` you need to first navigate to the Downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

then continue with the rest of the commands

Comment: The directions on the site tell me to just copy some commands and enter them into the terminal, and there is even a video that shows it being done, but they aren't working.  I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Paste the 3 short links into your browser and wait for the download to finish;
2. Move the .tar files to your home folder;
3. Run the rest of these commands in order, eliminate the 3 commands starts with "wget".